# A total sum of sequential numbers in PHP

Tags: php

This is a simple question,I guess, but I couldn't figure it out.

How do I get a total sum of sequential numbers in PHP  Like 2,4,6,8,10 . . . .1000

Thank you for the help.

Comment: 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10? Where is the pattern here?

Comment: No prime numbers greater than 2, duh. ;)

Comment: @GigaWatt I made the correction, sorry.

Comment: So you want a function to sum even numbers in the range a to b? Or do you have a string that looks like this as the current answers assume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$sum = array_sum(explode(',', '2,4,6,8'));`

edit: if you just want the sum of even numbers within a range you could

`$sum = array_sum(range(2,1000,2));`

Answer (score 4):

Split on `,` and then [sum](http://nl.php.net/array_sum):

```
$numbers = explode(",", $string);
$total = array_sum($numbers);
echo $total;
```

Note that this requires only `numbers` and `,` any other characters will be subject of being typecasted to an integer (which could result in unexpected results).

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to you could also use the [Arithmetic progression sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) and just do

```
$total = ($firstNumber + $lastNumber) * $count / 2
```

This will work as long as the numbers are a expressable in the format

a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>1</sub> + (n - 1)d

Your sequence could be described as

a<sub>n</sub> = 2 + (n - 1)2

So we can apply the Arithmetic progression sum and get

(2 + 1000) * 500 / 2 = 250,500

This will be much much faster than any `array_sum` method of calculating it.